# Maven - Configure an always run post execution job

Tags: maven

In my project POM file, I need to configure a **post execution step**. i.e. after running the testng unit tests, the post exec. job will parse the testng-xml-report and will generate a statistics page. The report generation will be done by a separate Jar. This Jar will be invoked in the `verify` phase of the POM.

But the current issue is, for the test success scenario in the `test` phase, it will invoke the Jar and works properly. For a failure case, xml report will be generated, but since the `test` phase is failing, it won't continue to the `verify` phase.

So is there any way I can specify a **must run**  case of **maven-exec-plugin**'s **exec** goal for Jar invocation, regardless the `test` phase is success or not.

Comment: Why are you using maven-exec-plugin to create reports? Doesn't they be printed by surefire/failsafe plugin ? Or better generated during site generation ?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Actually I have an xml parser Jar, which will takes surefire xml report as input and do some operations based on that.So after creation of surefire xml report in the `test` phase, I am interested to invoke the parser Jar using maven exec plugin in the `verify` phase

Comment: Than just bind the exec plugin to the verify phase and configure surefire not to fail for test failures which seemed to be not a really good idea.

Comment: I am not all interested in bypassing the surefire test failures, rather I would like to generate the xml report for success and failure scenarios. But in case of test failures, my requirement is `test` phase won't fail. With default maven life cycle, whenever a maven life cycle step fails, it won't run the **following** phases. I need to override this behaviour. Currently I am trying the `profiles` option suggested by _Aaron Digulla_. I will keep you informed the outcome through this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution for this scenario is not to fail the tests. The tests should record the failure (for example in the XML report) but the runner must return "success" to Maven.

For [Surefire](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore), you can achieve this with `-DtestFailureIgnore=true`

**EDIT** You can put this into your POM to activate it permanently.

But if you call maven with different targets, the results might be undesirable. For example for `mvn deploy`, you probably want the process to stop when there are test failures.

To fix this, you have two options:

1. Write a script that calls Maven with the necessary options to create a test report
2. Move the option into a [profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

**[EDIT]** Details about option #1: You can write a shell script that runs Maven with `-DtestFailureIgnore=true` to create the reports.

Then you need a utility that can locate the XML reports and check if there are any errors in it. If you use Java for this, call `System.exit(1)` if you find errors. If you prefer the command line, use [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to run a query against the XML and a tool like `find(1)` to locate the XML files. Post new questions if you need help for that.

Call this utility after Maven in your shell script with `util || exit 1` - that will stop the shell script with an error code of `1` if the utility finds an error.

Use this script to build instead of the embedded Maven runner.

Comment: I tried with combining both `-DtestFailureIgnore=true` with the maven **build profiles** and it is working as you suggested. But I need this maven project to be configured in a Contiguous Integration server like TeamCity. So if I gave `-DtestFailureIgnore=true`, then the build status will be always **GREEN** even if the test are failing. So it will mislead the user of the build configuration. Any way to execute all steps and fail at the end of build cycle. Also could you please details the first point in the above said two options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mvn -fn clean install`

The `-fn` stands for "fail-never", and it will always continue, even if a segment failed.

See `mvn -help` for more options